# mysql date and time filter

Tags: php, mysql, filter

can anyone please recommend where i can find documentation for the following :

I have a mysql table called  customer

```
----------------------------------
Name  +  Surname  +  Email +  DOB
---------------------------------
```

my DOB table format is : dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss

I have the html filter done for the form that lets you search "from date - " to date "

It does not post or do anything as i dont know how to make it filter by date.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to convert "from date" "to date" in dd-mm-yyyy formate.

then add WHERE condition in query as

```
WHERE DOB BETWEEN "from date 00:00:00" AND "to date 23:59:59"
```